# Colorpicker for .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf

I like the new Colorpicker in Extended WPF Toolkit, but it is for .NET 4.0 only.  http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home  Is there an equivalent for .NET 3.5 that is recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [this control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/09/25/colorpicker-control-for-wpf-silverlight.aspx) works with WPF and Silverlight. I'm not sure about the latest version, but the version in the blog should work with 3.5 Furthermore, if you see the last comment, it has a Color Picker created in C# (no XAML). ([Direct Link](http://livegeometry.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56298#913761)) This should also be compatible with 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of the Extended WPF Toolkit for .NET 3.5.

Check the second link on the downloads page for the binaries for 3.5:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/63863

The ColorPicker control should be in there -- I remember playing around with it a little while ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFColorPicker.aspx) in one of my projects with no problems.